# Using Laravel how to do two requests to the database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I want to do two requests to the database, one of them is for a filter and another is to load data of a person. Both of them must to be in the same form(people.blade.php)

Controller:

```
public function cargarDatosCompra(){       
    $empleados = empleadoModel::all();
    $producto = insumosModel::all(); // distinct EN LARAVEL ???? no funca ->distinct();
    $datos = [$producto, $empleados];
    
     return view('compra',['datos' => $datos]);
}

public function buscarMarca(Request $request){
    
    $listaDeProductos = insumosModel::where('marca','LIKE','%'.$request->get('selectProveedor').'%', 'AND','categoria','LIKE','%'.$request->get('selectCategoria').'%' )->get();
    
    $empleados = empleadoModel::all();
    $producto = insumosModel::all();
    $datos = [$producto, $empleados];

    return view('compra',['datos' => $datos],['prodFiltrado' => $listaDeProductos]);
```

I try to do with two forms, both of them were using with method post

Comment: What is the error you are getting? And which controller method ?

Comment: @user3783243 Laravel protects against SQL injections as long as not using raw sql statements https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#introduction

Answer (score 1):

Laravel query builder has a `distinct()` methods to pull records which are distinct. For the where condition involving check against two conditions with a logical AND you need to use parameter grouping by wrapping the where clauses within a where.

You can try

```php
public function cargarDatosCompra(){       
    $empleados = empleadoModel::all();
    $producto = insumosModel::distinct()->get(); // distinct EN LARAVEL ???? no funca ->distinct();
    $datos = [$producto, $empleados];
    
     return view('compra',['producto' => $producto, 'empleados' => $empleados]);
}

public function buscarMarca(Request $request){
    
    $listaDeProductos = insumosModel::where(function($query){
        $query->where('marca','LIKE','%'.$request->get('selectProveedor').'%')
            ->where('categoria','LIKE','%'.$request->get('selectCategoria').'%');
    })->get();
    
    $empleados = empleadoModel::all();
    $producto = insumosModel::distinct()->get();
    $datos = [$producto, $empleados];

    return view('compra',[
        'empleados' => $empleados,
        'producto' => $producto,
        'prodFiltrado' => $listaDeProductos        
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks u but I tried and nothing happened

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing happened" Pls elaborate - which method are your targeting and what is the expected output?

Comment: the method distinct() does not filter all the thing that came from the database, when I fill a <select> in my example.blade.php  this select fill with duplicate data